# JavaScript Function Calculator

Tags: javascript, function, math

I have so far:

```
function func(f,x) {
alert(f(x));
}

func(function(x) {return x*x;},2);
```

This works, but i am thinking that passing `function(x) {return x*x;},` is excessive and I could just pass `x*x`, as the idea is that I can supply (pretty much) any function.

I have tried:

```
function func(f,y) {
g=function() {return f;};
alert(g(y));
}

func(x*x,2);
```

amongst others, but I can't get it to work. Perhaps if I passed 'x*x' as a string..?

Comment: you can use Function("x", "return " + "x*x" ) for that. i would cache the output because it's (relatively) expensive to create functions this way, but the generated functions themselves run very fast (no closure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that the syntax is excessive, but for ES5 and before, that's just how it is.

However, in ES6 you can use the new ["arrow function"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) lambda syntax:

```
func(x => x * x, 2);
```

See http://www.es6fiddle.net/i4o5uj2l/

FWIW, the above `func` isn't great since it only supports *unary* functions, i.e. those taking a single parameter.   You could expand `func` to use ES6 "spread arguments":

```
function func(f, ...args) {
  console.log(f.apply(this, args));
}

func((x, y) => x * y, 3, 7);
> 21
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I have a way to do that using `eval` here http://jsfiddle.net/q5ayoszy/

```
function func(f,y) {

g=function()
{ x=y;
    return eval(f);
};
alert(g(y));
}

func('x*x',2);
```

Note : I pass the expression as a string and then use it inside the function.

You just need to assign the value of `y` to the variable `x` inside the function so  the `eval` evaluates correctly

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that with a string is by using the infamous `eval`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

```
var x = 2;

var y = eval("x * x"); //y = 4
```

But using eval is almost always a very bad idea.

Comment: Function() works better/faster/safer than eval() if you don't need closure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use currying to break down the process into smaller functions:

```
function multiply(x) {
    return function() {
      return x*x;
    }
}

var bytwo = multiply(2);

bytwo(); // 4
```

Comment: I think the OP's problem is more to do with passing function references at all, rather than strictly to do with currying.